# ЧПУ bitrix поиск выдает не правильную ссылку

Tags: битрикс, чпу

Столкнулся с проблемой настройки ЧПУ после перехода и обновления bitrix ngnix. 
Суть проблемы. Имеется новость по ссылке **www.test.ru/about_the_university/news/7967/** 
Если использовать поиск на сайте она находит новость но задает ей адрес **www.test.ru/7967/** 
Как привести их к одинаковым ссылкам? поиск очень нужен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполните [настройку инфоблока для корректного поиска элементов](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=2335).
Особое внимание уделите параметру "**URL страницы детального просмотра**".
В вашем случае настройки могут быть такими:

- URL страницы информационного блока - `#SITE_DIR#/about_the_university/news/`
- URL страницы раздела - `#SITE_DIR#/about_the_university/news/#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/`
- URL страницы детального просмотра - `#SITE_DIR#/about_the_university/news/#ELEMENT_ID#/`